# Unbound variable error when loading a procedure from an external file

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I'm using Chicken Scheme 4.9.0.1 on a Cloud9 hosted workspace, built from source.

I was trying it out with this (I mostly code with python, so I apologize for the weird parens syntax):

```
(define load-module
    (lambda (filepath) 
        (begin
            (load filepath)
        )
    )
)

(define print
    (lambda (command)
        (begin 
            (display command)
            (newline)
        )
    )
)

(load-module "../src/Basics.scm")
(print (exponent 5 2))
```

where exponent was:

```
(define (exponent num pow)
    (if (equal? pow 1)
        num
        (* num (exponent num (- pow 1))
        )
    )
)
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Started /home/ubuntu/workspace/test.scm

CHICKEN
(c) 2008-2014, The Chicken Team
(c) 2000-2007, Felix L. Winkelmann
Version 4.9.0.1 (stability/4.9.0) (rev 8b3189b)
linux-unix-gnu-x86-64 [ 64bit manyargs dload ptables ]
bootstrapped 2014-06-07

; loading /home/ubuntu/workspace/project1/src/test.scm ...
; loading ../src/Basics.scm ...

Error: unbound variable: pow

        Call history:

        <eval>    [append] (cons item (reverse target))
        <eval>    [append] (reverse target)
        <eval>    [append] (reverse (cons item (reverse target)))
        <eval>    [append] (cons item (reverse target))
        <eval>    [append] (reverse target)
        <eval>    [append] (reverse (cons item (reverse target)))
        <eval>    [append] (cons item (reverse target))
        <eval>    [append] (reverse target)
        <eval>    [append] (reverse (cons item (reverse target)))
        <eval>    [append] (cons item (reverse target))
        <eval>    [append] (reverse target)
        <syntax>          (print (exponent 5 2))
        <syntax>          (exponent 5 2)
        <eval>    (print (exponent 5 2))
        <eval>    (exponent 5 2)
        <eval>    [exponent] (equal? pow 1)     <--
```

I tried the same procedure on a different scheme implementation (biwascheme, using their online REPL) and it worked. When I added the code directly into the file that i was working on without loading it from a separate file, then it works.

Why does it give that unbound variable error only when it loads from a separate file?

Comment: It works fine for me. I tried it with `csi` and then tried compiling it with `csc`. I even reproduced the directory structure implied by your `load` statement to see if that had something to do with it.

Comment: Really? Ouch. Does that mean that there's something wrong with how I compiled CHICKEN?

Comment: I have no idea. I used the CHICKEN build from Debian's repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me. Compiled Chicken with the same version on Ubuntu, down to the specific revision.

Your call history looks very strange. More specifically:

```
    <eval>    [append] (reverse target)
    <syntax>          (print (exponent 5 2))
```

The `[append] (reverse target)` portion looks weird. Your exponent function (as described) does not call that. Even assuming the history was wrong and that was actually inside the `print` function, I've checked `library.scm` and that history does not make sense either.

This leads me to believe that the `Basics.scm` file being loaded is, for some reason, not the one you are expecting and you ended up with a different, non-working version of `exponent`.

You could ask Chicken to display the contents of the file to make sure. Something such as:

```
(with-input-from-file "../src/Basics.scm"
  (lambda () 
    (display (read))))
```

The result should match the expected content.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for that script, Stephen, it turns out that for some reason, the command `(load-module)` was loading up a totally different command that was also inside `Basics.scm`, and was interfering with the command that was supposed to execute. Commenting out the offending command fixed the issue.

Comment: The only question is *why* an unrelated command gotten mixed up in the call stack that way...

Comment: I am running into this issue as well. I'm not sure what the cause is. If I remove foreign-declare the issue goes away. I get the same thing with foreign-lambda.